# Node.JS Request - Invalid URI "/"

Tags: node.js, https, requestjs

I'm using `request` in my app to send a `POST` request over HTTPS with Client Authentication. Request always throws an error `Error: Invalid URI "/"` and I couldn't do anything to solve it. I've tried used url.parse instead of passing a string but it's still the same.

```
request.post({
        uri: 'https://localhost:5000',
        key: credentials.key,
        ca: credentials.ca,
        cert: credentials.cert,
        passphrase: credentials.passphrase,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }, { form: { data: payload }});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out it was caused by passing the second object to `request.post`, it should be inside the first object.

```
request.post('https://localhost:5000/', {
    key: credentials.key,
    ca: credentials.ca,
    cert: credentials.cert,
    passphrase: credentials.passphrase,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    form: { data: payload }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the issue was `request(options, {}`. Empty options. Your answer helped me spot my error.