# How to set the timeout for sending requests?

Tags: node.js

I have a cycle and I need this request to be sent every 3 seconds. How can do that?

```
request({
    url: `http://localhost:port/user/patch/${api.rows[j].id}`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Cookie': cookies
    }
},
function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('patch:', body)
}).form({
    Name: db.rows[i].NAME
})
```

Comment: Syntax error! You can use `setInterval` function.

Comment: I think the best thing is create a separate function for sending request. then put those things inside that function. then using `setTimeout(reqFun(), 3000);` method you can send a request

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 3000);
```

Please Try this JS code for send request in every three second

Comment: I tried to do it already, I get this error. `Error: Invalid URI "/"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186241/node-js-request-invalid-uri

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside a function and call the function recursively with a timer

```
function processData(){
   let db = ///Get the data from somewhere
   db.rows.forEach(row => {
     setTimeout(() => myJob(row), 3000)
   })
}

function myJob(row){
  request({
    url: `http://localhost:port/user/patch/${api.rows[j].id}`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Cookie': cookies
    }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
     console.log('patch:', body)
   }).form({
    Name: row.NAME
  })

}
```

Comment: If you do as you say, it will be `NAME` considered `undefined` - `Name: db.rows[i].NAME`

Comment: Where is variable `db` assigned? Do you want to send the requests in a loop?

Comment: Yes, I want to send a request in a loop

Comment: Edited the answer assuming that the call for each row needs to be made at a 3s interval